# expected class-name before '{' token c++

Tags: c++

I've been googling and reading about this and didn't come up with an answer yet, maybe someone can help me with this please.

the error I get is: expected class-name before '{' token

### Carte_num.h

```
#ifndef CARTE_NUM_H
#define CARTE_NUM_H
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Carte.h"

using namespace std;

class Partie;
class Carte_num : public Carte
{                      //<--------------this is where I get the error
    public:
        Carte_num(int haut,string typ, char coul [8], int nb_p);
        ~Carte_num();
   protected:
    int hauteur;
   public:


friend Partie;
};

#endif // CARTE_NUM_H
```

### Carte.h

```
    #ifndef CARTE_H
#define CARTE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Partie.h"

using namespace std;

class Joueur;
class Partie;
class Carte
{
    public:
        Carte();
        Carte( string typ, char coul [8], int nb_p);
        ~Carte();
    protected:
        char couleur[8];
        int nb_pts;
        string type;
    public:
        //bool action(Partie p);
        string definir();
        bool est_valable(Partie p);
        //int getnb_pts() { return(nb_pts);}

friend class Joueur;
friend class Partie;

};

#endif // CARTE_H
```

the error I get is: expected class-name before '{' token where I indicated earilier

Comment: which line is indicated in the error?

Comment: Possible circular dependency? What does `Carte.h` look like?

Comment: I think class carte is not visible for some reason.

Comment: class Carte_num : public Carte
{         //this is where the error is indicated
...
}

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with what's posted: I'd check that the carte.h you posted is *really* being included, by putting a `#error` directive in it somewhere. And check that your include guard CARTE_H isn't accidentally reused in a different header file.

Comment: Also, `using namespace std` in a .h file is not best practice. But won't cause your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `friend` declaration should be

```
friend class Partie;
```

Second, you need to include the `<string>` header, without the trailing `.h`. That is where `std::string` is defined.

Third, you could have a circular include dependency, for example if `Partie.h` includes `Carte.h` or `Carte_num.h`. You can fix that by removing `#include "Partie.h"` from `Carte.h` (you may need to include it in `Carte`'s implementation file).

Another possibility is that you have a missing `;` after your class `Carte` declaration in `Carte.h`.

Comment: the #include<string> doesn't solve the problem and I'm not missing ; after class Carte

Comment: @AbirBenYarou how about the `friend` declaration?

Comment: @AbirBenYarou then you could have a circular include dependency, see my edit.

Comment: @AbirBenYarou perhaps remove the `#include "Partie.h"` from `Carte.h`, and put it in the implementation file for `Carte`.

Comment: when I did that, I've got another error at Carte.h,   in the line class Partie; the error is: forward declaration of 'class Partie'

Comment: @AbirBenYarou I see, it is because you need the full definition in `Carte.h`, because if this: `bool est_valable(Partie p);`. You can change it to `bool est_valable(const Partie& p);` Basically, fwd declarations only work with pointers or references.

Answer (score 0):

Your `friend` declaration is incorrect.

See the correct format:

```
class Carte_num : public Carte
{       
    // ...    
    friend class Partie; 
};
```

Comment: that's not where the problem is

Comment: @AbirBenYarou : Then you have multiple Errors!! Like Circular dependency!! i think its already answered.